# How to do db table collate change using update script?

Tags: database, magento-1, sql, install-script

I am trying to make a collate change (DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci) to db but not sure how? (magento1.9)

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()

// how to do collate change here?
```

Help much appreciated,

Thanks
G

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SQL query in your install script:

```
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('your/table')}` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");
```

---

**Edit:**

I think there is no built-in method to change **tables** charset. There is only a method to change **columns** ...

```
$installer->getConnection()->changeColumn($tableName, $oldColumnName, $newColumnName, $definition);
```

Example from magento update script:

```
$installer->getConnection()->changeColumn($this->getTable('sales_flat_quote_item'),
    'weee_tax_applied', 'weee_tax_applied',
    'text CHARACTER SET utf8'
);
```

Comment: Hi @sv3n thanks that is what I currently have but we are looking for a "Zend-esque"/ORM way of doing it (if possible)

Comment: @gvanto as far as i know there is no Varien/Zend/Magento method to achieve this.